# What are the minimum software version requirements to run code on AWS?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I'm asking a general question but I am most interested in Ruby and Cassandra.

Does AWS (specifically EC2) block me from running an application with a very old version of Ruby or Cassandra?

Are the minimum software requirements listed anywhere?

Does AWS instead block software from running for other reasons, such as not installing security patches?

Or does AWS not do any sort of verification of what code I'm running on their servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All AWS customers should understand the [Shared Responsibility Model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/).

Specifically related to your question:

> Customers that deploy an Amazon EC2 instance are responsible for
>   management of the guest operating system (including updates and
>   security patches), any application software or utilities installed by
>   the customer on the instances, and the configuration of the
>   AWS-provided firewall (called a security group) on each instance.

No, AWS will not prevent you from running deprecated versions of Ruby or old, buggy web servers. It might notify you, however, in certain situations such as your RDS database having an expiring SSL certificate.

If your application behaves in a way that threatens the platform itself or other computer systems, for example being part of a DDoS botnet, then it's conceivable that AWS will implement measures to prevent it.